# Remove a div from RSS feed

Tags: php, filters, hooks, rss, feed

If someone can help to remove a div from my RSS feed. I want to remove below code from my RSS feed.

`<div class="well"> <a class="btn" href="foo.com">foo</a></div>`

Thanks in advance,
Gregory

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`the_content_feed`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed) hook for that. It is used to filter the content of the post after it is retrieved from the database and filtered by "the_content" and before it is sent to RSS reader (or browser).

So here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', function ( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace( '<div class="well"> <a class="btn" href="foo.com">foo</a></div>', '', $content );
    return $content;
} );
```

Comment: Hello Krzysiek Dróżdż, unfortunately the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Remember that feeds are cached by browsers - so most of the time you have to force-refresh them... Also make sure that the str_replace replaces exactly what you want.

Comment: The point is, if I change the content of the feed on new post I can see directly the new changes, also i use W3TC with rss purge settings on every new post. Many thanks for your help Krzysiek.

Comment: OK, so check two things. 1. Change `return $content;` to `return $content . 'adfkjslfjdlasd';` - do you see 'adfkjslfjdlasd' in the feed? 2. Change 'the_content_feed' to 'the_content' - do you see the div removed directly on the site?